# Retrieving xml value keeps returning Null

Tags: sql, xml

So essentially I have some data stored as XML in a table. What im trying to do is retrieve a specific value however, every time i try i get null.

I've taken a look around and looked at a bunch of posts on here. Im assuming its something to do with the namespace but im having no luck. Sample xml is as below:

```
<ns1:sometitle xmlns:ns1="http://address.com.au/some/address" rhboIsoNum="123456">
     <claim lengthOfStay="4">
     </claim>
  </ns1:onlineEligibilityCheckRequest>
```

I've tried the below and a variet of other combinations but im always getting null, any assistance would be great

```
    with XMLNAMESPACES (default 'http://address.com.au/some/address')
select 
    t.xmlconvert.value('(sometitle/claim/lengthOfStay)[1]','varchar(20)') cola
    from #test t
```

Comment: tag the database engine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lengthOfStay` is an attribute, not a child element, so you want `sometitle/claim/@lengthOfStay`

Also, `sometitle` is in a namespace while `claim` is not, so they need to be handled differently, but I'm not familiar with the SQL "with XMLNAMESPACES" syntax so I can't advise you on that.

Comment: Im not sure how i didnt pick that up bit adding the @ sign worked. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using oracle database you can use below

```
      create table t(data1 xmltype);  

    INSERT INTO t
    VALUES     ( Xmltype('<ns1:onlineEligibilityCheckRequest 
             xmlns:ns1="http://address.com.au/some/address"  
      rhboIsoNum="123456">
         <claim lengthOfStay="4">
         </claim>
      </ns1:onlineEligibilityCheckRequest>'));
```

Then select the data using the below statement

```
    SELECT Extractvalue(VALUE(p), '/claim/@lengthOfStay[1]')
    FROM   t,
           table(Xmlsequence(Extract((data1),
           '//ns1:onlineEligibilityCheckRequest/claim',
           'xmlns:ns1="http://address.com.au/some/address"'))) p;
```